# How to stop an image from going off screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cgpoint

I'm trying to make it so when you touch the `UIImage` it moves to a random spot, but it keeps going off the screen after two or more moves. I tried to reset it be for it moves to a random spot but it still ends up going off screen. 
So is there a way to tell if it goes off screen or am I just missing something?

```
-(IBAction)moveimage {
    int x = 240;
    int y = 160;

    image.center = CGPointMake(x, y);

    int xr = arc4random() % (int) self.view.frame.size.width;
    int yr = arc4random() % (int) self.view.frame.size.height;

    image.center = CGPointMake(xr, yr);
```

}

I'm still very new to iOS so any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful of your xr and yr type. CGPoint is a structure of 2 CGFloat (ie double on a 64bit architecture).

Answer (score 0):

```
int xr = arc4random() % (int) self.view.frame.size.width;

int yr = arc4random() % (int) self.view.frame.size.height;

xr = MAX(image.frame.size.width , xr); // left edge detect
xr = MIN(image.superview.frame.size.width - image.frame.size.width , xr); //right edge detect

yr = MAX(image.frame.size.height , yr); //  top edge detect
yr = MIN(image.superview.frame.size.height - image.frame.size.height , yr); //bottom edge detect 

image.center = CGPointMake(xr, yr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your code with the following:

```
CGFloat xRange = self.view.bounds.size.width - image.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat yRange = self.view.bounds.size.height - image.bounds.size.height;

CGFloat minX = self.view.center.x - (xRange / 2);
CGFloat minY = self.view.center.y - (yRange / 2);

int randomX = (arc4random() % (int)floorf(xRange)) + minX;
int randomY = (arc4random() % (int)floorf(yRange)) + minY;
image.center = CGPointMake(randomX, randomY);
```

Also, just a note on your original code, when you run the following:

```
int x = 240;

int y = 160;

image.center = CGPointMake(x, y);
```

Directly followed by this:

```
int xr = arc4random() % (int) self.view.frame.size.width;

int yr = arc4random() % (int) self.view.frame.size.height;

image.center = CGPointMake(xr, yr);
```

Your first assignment becomes unneccesary

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(IBAction)moveimage {

    int x = 240;
    int y = 160;

    image.center = CGPointMake(x, y);

    int newx =[self getRandomNumberBetween:self.view.bounds.size.width-imageWidth
                                 maxNumber:self.view.bounds.size.height-imageHeight];
    int newy =[self getRandomNumberBetween:self.view.bounds.size.width-imageWidth
                                 maxNumber:self.view.bounds.size.height-imageHeight];

    CGRect newFrame=[image frame];
    newFrame.origin.x = newx;
    newFrame.origin.y = newy;

    [image setFrame:newFrame];
}

- (NSInteger)getRandomNumberBetween:(NSInteger)min
                          maxNumber:(NSInteger)max{
    return min + arc4random() % (max - min + 1);
}
```